# Query for one column from database, but display two column for difference condition in table view

Tags: mysql

Here are my database "Stock", and "Quan":

```
item     model     Quantity
-----------------------------
    A         2       3                 
    A         3       4
    B         3       1
    C         3       1
    D         2       1
    E         2       1
    F         3       2
    G         2       2
```

Current code

```
Select stock.item, stock.model, stock.Quantity as model_2
FROM stock
WHERE stock.item ='2'
```

CURRENT display:

```
 item     model_2 
  --------------------
     A         3
     D         1
     E         1
     G         2
```

Do any way to display one more column with condition:

```
WHERE stock.item ='3'
```

So that I can display as below table?

```
item   model_2    model_3
----------------------------
A        2          4
B        0          1                  
C        0          1
D        1          0
E        1          0
F        0          2   
G        2          0
```

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You should add sample input data and then show us the output you expect, both as tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulus operator along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    item,
    CASE WHEN model % 2 = 0 THEN model ELSE 0 END AS even,
    CASE WHEN model % 2 = 1 THEN model ELSE 0 END AS odd
FROM abc;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there are another kind of data in actual case. Seems I have to use WHERE clause to encounter this issue.

What if I change to SELECT onetoten AS ODD, onetoten AS EVEN, can I split the result by WHERE clause?

Comment: It seems you forgot to add sample data to your question.  Please do that now.

Comment: Revised the questions be more reality, thanks for reminder

Comment: @WaiNokTang Answer updated per your latest information.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to use WHERE clause to realize the table?

Comment: Explain what "realize the table" means here.

Comment: Thanks again! I think I got terrible logic mistake in my mind. Missing one important parameter in the table. I revised the question, could you please advise again..